# Bootstrap 4 : How to control collapsible content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

How to control collapsible content in Bootstrap 4 ?

For example,this navbar as follow:

[image]

[image]
[image]

I want to control the status of this demo.
Specifically,
In status 2,I want the search inform not to be newline,still in one row.
In status 3，I want the search inform and navbar-brand not to be disappearing, the `ul` menu disappears only.

How to do it?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
        &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You only explained what you *don't* want. What do you want to happen with the form and menu items?

Comment: avoid using bootstrap 4 on live projects till a stable version of it is out

Comment: In status 2, suppose there is not enough room on one line for the form.. do you want the browser to have a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @Skelly no.   I want them to be reduced synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) explain how this works. Take any content out of the `collapse` that you don't want in the responsive toggleable menu. You may need to tweak the CSS to decrease the width of the form.

http://www.codeply.com/go/eaTFM5w3S6 (Alpha 2)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
        &#9776;
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
    <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div class="collapse pull-xs-left navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```